# Plotting inverse correlation

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Working in R on a data frame with two columns, unit price, units sold as UP and US respectively. The more units sold the less the price tends to be. I am trying to plot this relationship any way I can in R.

I have played around with `corr()` but cant seem to generate anything that makes sense.

The data looks like this:

[image: data]

What is the easiest way to plot this relationship?

Comment: Package `corrplot`, function `corrplot`. See also, for instance, [here](https://r-coder.com/correlation-plot-r/).

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question in R. Particularly, please include a reproducible example by editing the output of ``dput(head(data))`` into your original question. This will help people trying to answer your question. Thanks.